# Open file in IE

Tags: java

I am working on yet another project for work. For this project I am dealing with XML files, specifically my program allows a user to create an XML file based on multiple GUI options and JTable data. One feature that I would like to add is the ability for a user to open or view the created XML file with the click of a button.

In another program I created the user was able to generate a fixed-format text file known as .ACH. For this program the user was able to open the file in notepad using the following code:

```
public void displayFileOptionEdited(){



            int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Output file saved as "+Rewriter.location+ "\nWould you like to view the file?","Display Output",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

            if(dialogResult==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){

                ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("Notepad.exe", Rewriter.location);
                try {
                    pb.start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



        }

    }
```

The problem with my current program as that the XML file is just gibberish when viewed in notepad. The only way to view this file is by opening it in IE. (That I'm aware of). I did try one solution of creating a JDialog to view the file like this:

```
package view;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class XMLview extends JDialog {

    private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     */
    public XMLview(File file) {
        setBounds(100, 100, 555, 434);
        this.setTitle("XML Viewer");
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        {
            JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
            JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(textPane);
            Font font = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, 3,15);
            textPane.setFont(font);
            contentPanel.add(jsp);
             try {
                   textPane.read(new FileReader( file), null);
             } catch (IOException ex) {
                   System.out.println("problem accessing file"+file.getAbsolutePath());
             }
        }
        {
            JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
            buttonPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
            getContentPane().add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            {
                JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
                okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        dispose();
                    }
                });
                okButton.setActionCommand("OK");
                buttonPane.add(okButton);
                getRootPane().setDefaultButton(okButton);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The problem with this solution is that while the XML is generated into the JDialog it doesn't retain the proper formatting. Instead of taking up the couple hundred lines or so it is dragged out over 3 lines. The XML has over 60 tags so that may be the problem there - I am not really interested in taking this approach as I think it's going to be a major headache to figure out.

So my final solution is to simply open the file in IE when some action occurs. So we go back to my earlier example of opening a file with notepad. I realize that you can't do this with IE because it isn't a "system" utility like notepad. You would (I'm assuming) have to give a direct path which is difficult with multiple users.

Here is the thing - The users for this program all run the same system and have the same file layout for their PC. The only difference is the user name for their user directory. So I am wondering if it's possible to tell the program to open the file in IE, and how I would do it so that it can apply to all users even with different user names? If anyone knows of a way I'd greatly appreciate hearing it.

Likewise I am not able to post a full code because of the sensitive nature of the XML file content. I have tried finding another XML that could illustrate the same example but I am unable.

So to sum it up in case there is any confusion - I simply want the user to be able to click a button and the program to automatically open a file in IE.

Comment: I believe you can invoke IE, with `new ProcessBuilder("start", "iexplore", Rewriter.location).start()`, where `Rewriter.location` holds the path to your xml file.

Comment: Actually, `new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/C start iexplore your.xml").start();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Desktop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) system integration.

```
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("file:/... .xml"));
```

or `open(new File("... .xml"))`.

IE is registered for XML files, so this might be the shortest way.

Comment: Gives me an error:

java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\Users\jhamric\Documents\camt54CLEARED2016-05-11-10-17-42.xml
 

I did try using the "Catch" blocks.

Comment: Disregard. The second option worked perfectly, browse did not. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Use `file:/C:/Users/...` or `file:/C|/Users/...` or simpler, user `open(new File...` - spaces and such. - Okay read the second comment, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend to use something else than Desktop. Depending on IE is not the ideal solution.

I recommend to implement the XMLEditorKit.

Very easy to implement.

You can find everything here:
http://java-sl.com/xml_editor_kit.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing this with me. The entire program is written using Dom Parser with node building. Another program someone else created had used a JDialog but it still wasn't very organized and hard to read.. This actually looks like it could be very valuable and I may have to see about using it (I have to get any external download approved) but thanks for sharing with me, very cool!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this :

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
textPane.putClientProperty(JTextPane.HONOR_DISPLAY_PROPERTIES, Boolean.TRUE);
```

If you want to diplaying  Html contents in the JTextPane then you have to set for JTextPane#setContentType("text/html");

Comment: Well I just did.. That had a really strange effect. It actually put the tags inside of boxes - I have no idea why that happened.